# What is the default Project2ProjectTimeOut value using nuget restore?

Tags: nuget-package-restore

Our CI/CD process relies on nuget packages on GitHub and we intermittently run into a timeout error when running a nuget restore. I see there is a command line option -Project2ProjectTimeOut but I cannot find documentation for the default value. I would like to increase it to something greater than the default.

The documentation on the [nuget GitHub project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-restore) does not specify the value